# Error while setting object in NSMutableDictionary via lldb

Tags: objective-c, lldb

While debugging I need to replace a value in the immutable dictionary.
For that, I create a mutable dictionary from immutable and trying to set a value to this with `lldb` commands:

```
po NSMutableDictionary *$tmp = [(NSDictionary *) immutableDict mutableCopy]
po [$tmp setObject:@"object" forKey:@"key"]
```

But `lldb` fails with error:

`error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<NSCopying> _Nonnull' with an rvalue of type 'NSString *'
passing argument to parameter 'aKey' here`

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: can please tell us how you initialize immutableDict ?

Comment: @HiteshSultaniya it initialize some were in app and I catch it on breakpoint

Comment: okay can you just add what is in there in immutableDict ?

Comment: I can't get this to fail with the latest Xcode 9.  What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @HiteshSultaniya string keys and string values

Comment: @JimIngham Xcode 9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this script:

```
expression [mutableDict setValue:@"newObject" forKey:@"key"];
```

this is `setObject:forKey:` definition:

```
- (void)setObject:(ObjectType)anObject forKey:(KeyType <NSCopying>)aKey;
```

the key should follow `NSCopying` protocol.

and `setValue:forKey:` definition:

```
- (void)setValue:(nullable ObjectType)value forKey:(NSString *)key;
```

the key kind of class `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this way,

```
NSDictionary *dictTemp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"Value1",@"value2"] forKeys:@[@"Key1",@"Key2"]];
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dictTemp];
```

Output with lldb,

```
Printing description of mutableDict:
{
    Key1 = Value1;
    Key2 = value2;
}
(lldb) po [mutableDict setObject:@"Value3" forKey:@"Key3"]
(lldb) po mutableDict
{
    Key1 = Value1;
    Key2 = value2;
    Key3 = Value3;
}

(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into this in Xcode 10, there seems to be a flaw in the debugger that sometimes (but not always) fails to do necessary type coercion that happens faithfully in compiled code.  The fact that it doesn't always happen makes it especially disconcerting when it does happen, and there's very little written about it.

I don't fully understand the details, but thankfully there is an easy fix.  (At least it has worked for me every time I've run into it.)  Simply cast the type of the key to `id`, as follows:

```
(lldb) expr check[(id)@"check_id"]= @"383027"
(NSTaggedPointerString *) $6 = 0xb0b97b49f6ae12f7 @"383027"
```